# Explanation of this Regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm not very good with Regular Expressions, and I didn't fully understood this one, All I get from this is that it find every **h1** and add a class to it's last word.

```
$("h1").html(function(index, old) {
    return old.replace(/(\b\w+)$/, '<span class="myClass">$1</span>');
});
```

I'm trying to make it work by last two characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (poorly written) regex finds a sequence of word characters (latin letters, numbers and underscore) at the end of the input. The same can be achieved much simpler: `/\w+$/`, so neither `\b` nor parens are actually necessary here.

To match two last words you'll need something like

```
/\w+(?=(\W+\w+)?$)/g
```

which means "a word, optionally followed by another word before the end of the input".

To match two last characters -- well, this is something you should be able to figure out on your own (hint: any character is `.` (dot) in regex language).

Comment: And how can i get the last two characters?

Comment: @CaioKawasaki: hold on, why did you make this edit? He asked for words, not characters???

Comment: @CaioKawasaki: not quite. "Character, character, end-of-string" - just translate that literally.

Comment: @georg I am of his team, and he wrote the wrong word... So, it should be: /(.{2})$/ ?

Comment: @CaioKawasaki: The last expr is correct, but you don't need a group here, and `.{2}` is actually longer than just `..`. So,  `/..$/` will do the job (_unless_ your string contains newline characters, which are not matched by `.`).

Comment: @CaioKawasaki: not at all. One more advice - if you drop the group `(...)`, you have to use `$&` (=whole match) instead of `$1` (=group 1) in your replacement string.

Comment: Yes, at first I thought it strange change the text for a $1, but took a quick search, and I have found the explanation. Thank @georg

Answer (score 5):

Here is and explanation:

```
/       : regex delimter
  (     : begin capture group #1
    \b  : word boundary
    \w+ : one or more word character (same as [a-zA-Z0-9_]+)
  )     : end of group
  $     : end of string
/       : regex delimiter
```

It matches the last word of the string, ie the last word of the h1 tag.

Comment: It's hard for me to see things with beginner's eyes, but I don't think this "explanation" actually explains anything. Show him _why_ he needs `\b` and all this stuff (hint: he doesn't).